# is it possible to override "if" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So, 
I know it's possible to override functions like `alert()` ,`confirm()` ...etc as the following:

```
window.alert = function(x){
// do something
}
```

My question is, is it possible to do the same with if statements?

```
window.if = function(x){
// etc
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: 'if' is not a function, therefore: nope.

Comment: `if` is a language construct, not a function, so no, you can't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` isn't a function. It's a built-in statement of the language, so no, it can't simply be overwritten.

Changing the meaning of `if` wouldn't be desirable in 99.9999% of cases anyway. You could potentially break all other code that may come into use on your site.

If you wanted to create your own version, it's not that difficult:

```
function myIf(predF, thenF, elseF) {
    if (predF()) {
        thenF()
    } else {
        elseF()
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
myIf(() => 5 < 10,
    () => console.log("It works!"),
    () => console.log("It's broken!")
)
```

Then make any changes you want to that function.

(It should be noted though that using the function above is probably a terrible idea. It's just an example).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Will do, but can't accept an answer unless it's 10 minutes later.. that's how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @user7873148 Just purely out of curiosity, but what changes did you need to make to `if` that prompted this question?

Answer (score 0):

`If` is a **reserved keyword** in javascript language it is not a function.

**keywords** are like `alphabets` of a language you don't change meaning of alphabets of a language it doesn't make sense.

For more information on other reserved keywords click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)